# Exe file created by cX_Freeze version 6.1 is detected as virus by Kaspersky

Tags: python, cx-freeze

For a particular requirement, I have written code in python and created the exe file using **cx_Freeze version 6.1**. When I tried to use in another system, it is detected as virus and removed automatically by Kaspersky antivirus. Currently I am using **Python version 3.8.1** and **cx_Freeze version 6.1**. I provide below the setup.py to create the exe file. It is a console based application to be used by other applications. I am using a third party library called `ntplib` for NTP validation. Please help and guide me where I am doing wrong.

```
import shutil

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

includes = ["net_util", "cx_Freeze", "platform", "subprocess"]
excludes = ["tkinter", "test", "unittest", "pydoc", "http", 'multiprocessing.Pool']
packages = ["os", "platform", "net_util", "concurrent", "subprocess", "platform"]
build_exe_options = {"excludes": excludes, "optimize": 2}
mainScript = "main.py"
exeIcon = "icons/ping.ico"
exeName = "validation.exe"

base = None

exe = Executable(script=mainScript, base=base, icon=exeIcon, targetName=exeName)
shutil.rmtree('build', ignore_errors=True)

setup(name="validation",
      version="0.1",
      description="My Network util console application!",
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=[exe])
```

The sample code is available in the following github location [github link](https://github.com/debjava/py-x-ping1).

Find below the screenshot from Kaspersky.
[image]

Please help me to resolve.

Comment: This FAQ may be helpful. [False detections by Kaspersky products. What to do?](https://support.kaspersky.com/us/1870?_ga=2.268732401.1682414375.1592212745-1455514341.1592212745)

Comment: Did you do any research? What results? Also, did you try a simple "hello world" python and use cx_freeze on it, does that have the same virus warning? Did you look on cx_freeze gitub issues?

Comment: if you create a simple program with hello world also using cx_Freeze and Pyinstaller, most of the antivirus program detects. Earlier I tried with Pyinstaller, it was detected by McAFee. Before posting, I tried other options available in internet.

Comment: I use PyInstaller all the time with absolutely no virus false alerts. If it’s such a serious issue for you, best to ask on the cx_freeze github issues.